# Reading an IP address in Python

Tags: python, ip

I am working with a Python script (written by a colleague) which takes output files and scrapes the IP address and results of ping commands to determine reach-ability status.  The issue:  The script is scraping the subnet mask and not the host IP.  I don't understand why the regex doesn't match the IP address.  Below is the code and a sample of the output file generated by the script:

```
enter code here


import glob
import re
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import ntpath

new_file = []
results_file = []
success_file = []
failure_file = []
new_count = 0
regex_clean = re.compile('ip address')
regex_source = re.compile('ip address')
regex_destination = re.compile('chos to')
regex_success = re.compile('!')
regex_failure = re.compile('\.\.\.\.\.|U\.U\.U')
regex_ip_address = re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
regex_final_success = re.compile('SUCCESS')
regex_final_failure = re.compile('FAILURE')


def find_files(files_directory):
    file_list = []
    os.chdir(files_directory)
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        # print(files_directory + '/' + file)
        file_list.append(files_directory + '/' + file)
    return file_list


def clean_data(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        h = f.readlines()
        for num, line in enumerate(h):
            if regex_clean.search(line) is not None:
                for line2 in h[num-1:num+12]:
                    new_file.append(line2)
                    # print(new_file)
    return new_file


def find_results(new_file):
    for num, line in enumerate(new_file):
        if regex_success.search(line) is not None:
            test_status = 'SUCCESS!'
            if test_status:
                results_file.append('Test Status: ' + test_status)
            # print(results_file)
        if regex_failure.search(line) is not None:
            test_status = 'FAILURE!'
            if test_status:
                results_file.append('Test Status: ' + test_status)
            # print(results_file)
        if regex_source.search(line) is not None:
            source_address = regex_ip_address.findall(line)
            if source_address:
                for ip in source_address:
                    results_file.append('Configured Address: ' + ip)
            # print(results_file)
        if regex_destination.search(line) is not None:
            destination_address = regex_ip_address.findall(line)
            if destination_address:
                for ip in destination_address:
                    results_file.append('Destination Address: ' + ip)
            # print(results_file)
    return results_file


def create_final_files(results_file):
    for num, line in enumerate(results_file):
        # print(line)
        # print("1")
        if regex_final_success.search(line) is not None:
            for line2 in results_file[num-2:num+1]:
                success_file.append(line2)
                # print('SUCCESS FILE')
                # print("2")
                # print(success_file)
                # print('SUCCESS FILE')
        elif regex_final_failure.search(line) is not None:
            for line3 in results_file[num-2:num+1]:
                failure_file.append(line3)
                # print('FAILURE FILE')
                # print("3")
                # print(failure_file)
                # print('FAILURE FILE')
    return success_file, failure_file


def clean_filename(file):
    head, tail = ntpath.split(file)
    return tail


def create_output_files(success_file, failure_file, save_directory, filename):
    success_filename = save_directory + "/SUCCESS_FILE.txt"
    failure_filename = save_directory + "/FAILURE_FILE.txt"

    with open(success_filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n\n")
        f.write("SOURCE FILE: %s\n" % filename)
        f.write("\n")
        for item in success_file:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

    with open(failure_filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n\n")
        f.write("SOURCE FILE: %s\n" % filename)
        f.write("\n")
        for item in failure_file:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    print('Welcome to the quick REGEX script!')
    print('This will take ping outputs and return the device IP addresses, and successes, failures in two files.\n')
    print('Select directory containing ping files:')
    files_directory = askdirectory()
    print('FILE DIRECTORY: ' + files_directory)
    print('\n')
    print('Select directory to use for created files:')
    save_directory = askdirectory()
    print('SAVE DIRECTORY: ' + save_directory)
    file_list = find_files(files_directory)
    file_count = len(file_list)
    print('TOTAL FILES: ' + str(file_count))
    # print(file_list)
    for n, file in enumerate(file_list):
        new_count = new_count + 1
        percent_complete = (new_count / file_count) * 100
        print('PERCENT COMPLETE: ' + str(percent_complete) + '%')
        new_file = []
        results_file = []
        success_file = []
        failure_file = []
        # print(type(file))
        # print(file)
        new_file = clean_data(file)
        results_file = find_results(new_file)
        results_file = find_results(new_file)
        # print('RESULTS FILE')
        # print (results_file)
        # print('END OF RESULTS FILE')
        success_file, failure_file = create_final_files(results_file)
        # print('SUCCESS FILE')
        # print(success_file)
        # print('END OF SUCCESS FILE')
        # print('FAILURE FILE')
        # print(failure_file)
        # print('END OF FAILURE FILE')
        filename = clean_filename(file)
        # print('FILE NAME: ' + filename)
        create_output_files(success_file, failure_file, save_directory, filename)
    print('COMPLETE!')
    sleep(5)

    root.destroy()
```

Sample of source file:

```
sh run | include ip address
 ip address AAA.BBB.CCC.136 255.255.255.128
ping AAA.BBB.67.97

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to AAA.BBB.67.97, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 142/142/143 ms
ping AAA.BBB.75.97

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to AAA.BBB.75.97, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 134/134/135 ms
```

Sample script output:

```
Configured Address: 255.255.255.192
Destination Address: AAA.BBB.67.97
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Configured Address: 255.255.255.192
Destination Address: AAA.BBB.67.97
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Destination Address: AAA.BBB.75.97
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Configured Address: 255.255.255.192
Destination Address: AAA.BBB.67.97
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Configured Address: 255.255.255.192
Destination Address: AAA.BBB.67.97
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Test Status: SUCCESS!
Destination Address: AAA.BBB.75.97
Test Status: SUCCESS!
```

Comment: Are you asking why an input string like `AAA.BBB.CCC.136` isn't matched by a regex like `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`?

Comment: Meanwhile, please read [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dumping all of your code on us with no indication of what part of that code is relevant is not a good way to get help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sorry about dumping all the code; I wasn't sure how much to include for the example.  I scrubbed the IP addresses when I uploaded the question; old habit.  I'm relatively sure that the first octet of the host addresses will all either be single, or double digit.  If I change the regex to '\d{1,2}' for the first octect, will that pick it up?

Comment: re: " wasn't sure how much to include for the example" The answer is "as little as possible". Since you're asking about how to use a regex to parse a string, all you really need is a couple of lines of code that defines the string to parse and the pattern you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  I will definitely take more caution when venturing into this arena in the future!

Comment: I'm still confused about whether your real input data is actual IP addresses, or those `AAA.BBB.CCC.136` things. If it's the latter, it's not digits, so you can't match it as digits. If it's the former, you need to provide example data that actually demonstrates your problem. For example, you can use made-up private-range addresses that don't expose any sensitive data but can actually be parsed by (a working version of) your code.

Comment: I also still can't tell if it's "source file" or "sample script output" that you're trying and failing to parse here. If it's the latter, we don't need to see the source file or the script that processes it at all. If it's the former, is that expected output, or actual output, or what? At any rate, most of the patterns defined in your code don't seem to match anything in _either_ of the two, so it's not clear what they're intended to do, or what parts are and aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

> The script is scraping the subnet mask and not the host IP.
>   I don't understand why the regex doesn't match the IP address.

Your regular expression is looking for 3 decimal numbers (composed of 1 to 3 digits) separated with dots. So it finds the subnet mask "255.255.255.192" while it doesn't find "AAA.BBB.67.97".

By the way, string like "AAA.BBB.67.97" is **not** an IP address.